# How to set the initial width can use QListWidget and use splitter to adjust the size？

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

hi，I want to set the initial width can use QListWidget，and use splitter to adjust the size.

I want such as this.
[image]

but now，when I use the splitter, is like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to set initial sizes of `QSplitter` children using Qt Designer. Once you've converted from .ui to .py, you can set the size of each pane using `setSizes(list_of_sizes)`. i.e. for a two-pane window:

```
splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter()
splitter.setSizes((50,100))
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `QSplitter` class, you have the [`setSizes` method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#setSizes), which is basically a list of width corresponding to each children

```
QList<int> widgetsWidth;
widgetsWidth << 100 << 100 << 100 << 400;
ui->mySplitter->setSizes(widgetsWidth);
```